# Ssh key Gitlab and eclipse on MAC

Tags: git, eclipse, gitlab, ssh-keys

I use MAC. I am generating ssk key here: Pereferens>General>network connections>ssh2> key managment> Generate DSA key and also RSA key (tried both). Save it and put it in gitlab. Cloned ssh link from a repository and went back to eclipse and failed with this. Auth fail:invalid password or missing ssh key. Are you familiar with it, how you solve it??

Comment: "went back to eclipse and failed with this" What did you do in Eclipse that caused that failure?

Comment: Gitlab belong to school. Nothing, have not change any setting. Succecced with github but not gitlab.

Comment: I mean what are the steps that made this happen.

Comment: Just tried to make ssh key work and did not go to any other setting. You have Mac and are connected gitlab??

Comment: why don't you use `/usr/bin/ssh-keygen` to generate you keys , take a look here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/. And also check your gitconfig: `git config -e --global` or `--local`

Comment: @dejdej Eclipse has this built-in. This question is about Eclipse, not the command line Git, which may not even be installed.